# RemoteApp in Windows XP opens Remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have made Remote App .msi paket. Im able to install it to windows XP but it's opening remote desktop in stead of remote app. Problen occures only with one pc, other xp comuter working fine.

What should I try to make it open correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need in Windows XP is SP3 because RemoteApp requires Remote Desktop version 7.0 which isn't available in XP SP2 or prior you have to installed Service Pack 3 for this.